# Is it possible possible to add an object to the ObjectDataSource's InsertParameters collection? [as opposed to a string]

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm invoking the ObjectDataSource **InsertMethod** programmatically. I've tried so save a couple of text boxes' value to the DB using the **InsertParameters.Add()** method, and it worked perfectly.

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("CoName", CompanyNameBox.Text);
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("Phone", PhoneBox.Text);         
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Now, given that I have an important number of variables, I've regrouped those variables in one object.

Now, it looks like there's no overload method that allow me to add a parameter accepting an object to the collection.

What the best way to do that? Any other alternative?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your paramaters will have to be provided one by one in your code, that is to say one call to add a parameter per property of your custom object.

Comment: You mean, no way of sending o custom object in one shot?

Comment: As far as I know, no. That's what the entity model has been created for I'm afraid.

Comment: No problem. It's good to know so that I do not waste time. Thank you.